# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)-Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running ubuntu 22.04.1 -I just installed VirtualBox and im getting this error when running a Kali machine on it.

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Comment: Disable secure boot.

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks a lot -it works